# Stop holding 'this' in a temp variable

Tags: javascript

I am continually having to hold `this` in a temp variable in order to access it in other functions.  For example in the two methods below, I am holding `this` in a `that` variable:

```
startTimer: function () {
    var that = this;

    if ($('#defaultCountdown:hidden'))
        $('#defaultCountdown').show('slow');
    shortly = new Date();
    shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('change', { until: shortly,
        layout: '<ul id="errorList"><li>Next update in <b>{snn}</b> {desc}</li></ul>',
        description: 'seconds',
        onExpiry: function () {
            that.performUpdate();
        }
    });
},
performUpdate: function () {
    var that = this;

    this.message.fetch({
        success: function () {
            $('#calleesStatuses').html('');
            that.callees.refresh(that.message.get("Callees"));
            $('#defaultCountdown').hide('slow');
            that.startTimer();
        },
        error: function (request, settings) {
            that.killCountDown();
            showErrorMessage(request.responseText)
        }
    });
},
```

Is there anyway around this or could I possibly use `apply`?

Comment: `apply` still requires you to have a reference to the `that` so that you can apply the function to the `that` object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECMAScript 5 introduced [**`Function.bind()`**<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), so it is only supported by newer browsers. An alternative implementation can be found in the documentation I linked to. If you include it in your code, you can use `bind()` in the other (older) browsers too.

It lets you set the object `this` should refer to in the function. So you could write:

```
performUpdate: function () {    
    this.message.fetch({
        success: function () {
            $('#calleesStatuses').html('');
            this.callees.refresh(this.message.get("Callees"));
            $('#defaultCountdown').hide('slow');
            this.startTimer();
        }.bind(this),
        error: function (request, settings) {
            this.killCountDown();
            showErrorMessage(request.responseText)
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
```

Comment: that.message.get should be this.message.get, no?

Comment: It is worth noting that ECMAScript 5 is a draft and if you have to support old browsers like IE6/7 you are completely out of luck.

Comment: @Andrew: As said, the link to the MDC documentation provides an alternative implementation. It is not even supported by IE8.

Comment: Just as a note, if those compatibility tables are correct, this should work with FF/Chrome users, but IE users must have the latest version (IE9), and Opera/Safari users are out of luck. (**Edit:** Posted this before the page refreshed with Andrew's comment.)

Comment: @Bryan: That is why I pointed out that one can find an alternative implementation in the documentation.

Comment: @Felix Did you forget to submit an edit or something? I don't see any reference to the MDC documentation in your post. Also, just for reference: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: @Andrew: Third word, `Function.bind()` is a link. Tried to make it a bit more obvious.

Comment: @Felix oh, that's a cool trick. I didn't know you could do that and it didn't register with me that it was blue. You learn something new every day :) I like the new more obvious link better though.

Answer (score 1):

<s>No, there isn't.</s> The value of `this` will be different in the closure than it is in the scope that the closure is defined so the only way to make it cleaner is to define it on an object level so at least you only have to do it once per object, which it looks like you are already doing anyway.

Edit:

Strike out the "No there isn't" because `bind` is a valid alternative and there are comparability implementation (see other answer). Although I personally think `var self = this;` is cleaner and you only need to define it once per object but it is a matter of preference at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the simplest way to do it. This is what I do (although I'm writing GWT code), to reference the `this` of the wrapping function in an inner anonymous function.

Even if something like `this.wrappingMethod.this` were/are possible, storing the the `this` in a variable named according to your taste is a lot more readable (you could use a more descriptive name, ofcourse), and (still assuming you cold somehow reference the wrapping scope) it will be more robust since you could introduce another level without having to rewrite all the references.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's no comfort, but not really if the original `this` is the only context in which you can execute functions like `startTimer` and `killCountdown`. What I'd recommend is giving it a more meaningful name, like `timer` or something. Really, `this` is just a convenient keyword for referring to the owner of whatever we're executing, and it *should* change as the owner changes. If "this/that" is becoming hard to read, the solution is to change the name from `that` to something more semantically meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is a standard pattern in JavaScript, except that it's traditional to use `self` instead of `that`. But you can use the `bind()` method  like this:

```
onExpiry: performUpdate.bind(this);
```

if you're working with a framework that extends the prototype of `Function` to include it, or your Javascript interpreter is recent enough. (`bind` creates the same sort of anonymous function behind the scenes, but is arguably less efficient since it has to deal with all sorts of special cases).

Comment: Crockford uses `that`, and therefore a lot of other JavaScript developers use it too. Personally, I wish they didn't—it's too similar to `this`. `self` looks very different.